# How do I access the data of an Akka Http GET request?

Tags: scala, akka, httprequest

The [scala tutorial](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-and-response.html) site gives this example:

```
HttpRequest(uri = "https://akka.io")

// or:
import akka.http.scaladsl.client.RequestBuilding.Get
Get("https://akka.io")
```

How do I access the data? I.e. How do I do the equivalent of

```
io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
```

Comment: Is the following documentation page what you're looking for? https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html

Comment: Hmm yes actually, I believe so. Thanks